# "ERROR: multiple drivers on net" when setting a register on both positive and negative edges

Tags: verilog, fpga

I was following a tutorial on SPI master in Verilog. I've been debugging this for about three hours now and cannot get it to work.

I've been able to break down the issue into a minimum representative issue. Here are the specifications:

We have two states, `IDLE` and `COUNTING`. Then, on the `clock` positive edge, we check:

- If the state is `IDLE`, then the `counter` register is set to 0. If while in this state the `dataReady` pin is high, then the `state` is set to `COUNTING` and the `counter` is set to all 1s.
- If the state is `COUNTING`, the state remains `COUNTING` as long as `counter` is not zero. Otherwise, the state is returned to `IDLE`.

Then, we count on the negative edge:

- On the negative edge of `clock` if `state` is `COUNTING`, then decrement `counter`.

Here's the code I came up with to fit this specification:

```
// look in pins.pcf for all the pin names on the TinyFPGA BX board
module top (
    input CLK,    // 16MHz clock
    input PIN_14,
    output LED,   // User/boot LED next to power LED
    output USBPU  // USB pull-up resistor
);
    // drive USB pull-up resistor to '0' to disable USB
    assign USBPU = 0;

    reg [23:0] clockDivider;
    wire clock;

    always @(posedge CLK)
        clockDivider <= clockDivider + 1;

    assign clock = clockDivider[23];

    wire dataReady;
    assign dataReady = PIN_14;


    parameter IDLE = 0, COUNTING = 1;
    reg state = IDLE;

    reg [3:0] counter;

    always @(posedge clock) begin
        case (state)
            IDLE: begin
                if (dataReady)
                    state <= COUNTING;
            end
            COUNTING: begin
                if (counter == 0)
                    state <= IDLE;
            end
        endcase
    end

    always @(negedge clock) begin
        if (state == COUNTING)
            counter <= counter - 1;
    end

    always @(state) begin
        case (state)
            IDLE:
                counter <= 0;
            COUNTING:
                counter <= counter;
        endcase
    end

    assign LED = counter != 0;
endmodule
```

With this, we get the error:

```
ERROR: multiple drivers on net 'LED' (LED_SB_DFFNE_Q.Q and LED_SB_DFFNE_Q_1.Q)
```

Why? There is literally only one assign statement on the LED.

Comment: You are assigning `counter` variable in two different `always` blocks, that's not allowed in Verilog.

Comment: So how is this supposed to be done? The counting necessarily needs to happen in the negative edge (as this is SPI and so I need to put out the data on the negative edge).

Comment: @ThorCorreia just use always @ (clock) and test for whether it's posedge or negedge in side the always block.  If it's not positive, you can be pretty sure it's negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it would not be easy to come up with a synthesizable model in such a case. But, you do not need any negedge logic to implement your model. Also you made several mistakes and violated many commonly accepted practices.

Now about some problems in your code.

1. By using non-blocking assignment in the clock line you created race condition in the simulation which will probably cause incorrect simulation results:

```
always @(posedge CLK)
        clockDivider <= clockDivider + 1; // <<< this is a red flag!
assign clock = clockDivider[23];
...
always @(posedge clk)
```

2. you incorrectly used nbas in your always block

```
always(@state)
... counter <= conunter-1; // <<< this is a red flag again!
```

3. your state machine has no reset. Statements like `reg state = IDLE;` will only work in simulation and in some fpgas. It is not synthesizable in general.  I suggest that you do not use it but provide a reset signal instead.

Saying that, i am not aware of any methodology which would use positive and negative edges in such a case. So, you should not. All your implementation can be done under the posedge, something like the following. However

```
always @(posedge clock) begin
   if (reset) begin  // i suggest that you use reset in some form.
      state <= IDLE;
      counter <= 0;
   end
   else begin
        case (state)
            IDLE: begin
                if (dataReady) begin
                    state <= COUNTING;
                    counter <= counter - 1; 
                end
            end
            COUNTING: begin
                if (counter == 0) 
                    state <= IDLE;
                else 
                    counter <= counter - 1;
            end

        endcase
    end
end
```

I hope i did it right, did not test.

Now you do not need the other two always blocks at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Why are 1 and 2 bad? What would be the alternative? This is exactly what icestudio's prescaler snippet does. What's the race condition?

Comment: #1 will might cause clock/data race because of the way non-blocking assignments are implemented in *simulation*. #2 can cause similar issues if used in no-sequential logic. You need to read about recommended uses of  blocking/non-blocking assignments in verilog.